# How to split a string into two lines with a two character delimiter

Tags: regex, awk, split

I have a lot of this lines:

```
<anyword1.> 1. Blablabla .> 2 blablabla .> 3 blablabla
```

And I need this:

```
<anyword.> 1. Blablabla .> 2 blablabla .> 3 blablabla
```

I thought about split line in two lines using ".>" separator:

```
A="<anyword1"
B=" 1. Blablabla .> 2 blablabla .> 3 blablabla"
```

Then remove the number 1 in A and finally merge A".>"B

The problem is I can get A with awk:

```
awk -F ".>" '{ print $1 }'
```

But how to get B? Is there any way to split to the end of the string from the first separator ".>" ?

I tried to use cut command but cut only allows one character separator.

PD. "anyword" this string can have '.' that is why I need the two character separator.

Comment: To have that separator treated as "dot greater-than" instead of "any-character greater-than", you have to `-F '\\.>'` or `-F "\\\\.>"` -- you have to pass the appropriate number of escapes to awk.

Comment: @Gea - That is a very odd approach vs just `sed 's/1//'` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
awk -F ".>" '{print $1}'
awk -F ".>" '{$1=""; print}'
```

? :)

Comment: You'll probably want to specify `-v OFS=".>"`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/(.*?).> (.*)/ { a= $1;$1="";b=$0;print a,b}'
```

in this way you have both `a` and `b` in single line

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like what you want is to replace the first occurrence of `1.>` on each line with `.>`? If so, then you can write:

```
sed 's/1[.]>/.>/'
```